# Setting radio boxes to be checked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a page with some radio buttons that I want to be checked on page load. This is the jQuery that I'm using:

```
$('.optionHolder').find('input').first().attr('checked', 'true');
```

The one's I want checked are the first input elements of each `.optionHolder` on the page. At the moment there are two, but the code above is only checking one. Take a look at the image:

[image: http://imgur.com/NQkei.jpg]

As you can see, only the first set is being checked.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suggest posting your html code as well. Makes error searchign easier.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('.optionHolder input:first-child').attr('checked', true);
```

`first()` will select the first element in a collection, whereas `:first-child` will select each element only if it is the first child of its parent.

`:first` works by selecting the first input element that is a child of `.optionHolder`:

```
$('.optionHolder input:first')
```

Comment: had to use: `.find('input:first')` but your solution works, thanks! :)

Comment: @Nick, I just removed the *first()* and expanded the OP's selector for *find()*.  I'll update it :-) I was looking for a link but the jQuery site is down.

Comment: @Will: it depended on your HTML structure really - I've updated my answer with your solution too.